# Python Questionnaire Validation with Recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion, logic

I've created a function in Python to review a series of questions in a dictionary and remove records from the dataset depending on the answers to the questionnaire. I've created the questionnaire so the user can only respond *yes* or *no*. I have a third branch to handle the case where the user responds with something other than *yes* or *no*, but I want the function to repeat the existing question. Currently, it goes back and restarts from the first question. What can I add to fix this functionality?

For reference, here is the function I created:

```
def questionnaire(df, questions = questions):
    for i in range(0, len(questions)): #len(questions)-1):
        print(list(questions.keys())[i])
        
        ans = str(input())
        if ans.lower() == 'yes':
            if list(questions.values())[i][1] == "Yes":
                df = df[df.Section.isin(list(questions.values())[i][0]) == False]
        elif ans.lower() == 'no':
            if list(questions.values())[i][1] == "No":
                df = df[df.Section.isin(list(questions.values())[i][0]) == False]
        else:
            print("Please type yes or no.")
            questionnaire(df, questions = questions)
        
    return df
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your problem:

```py
def questionnaire(df, questions=questions):
    for i in range(0, len(questions)):  #len(questions)-1):
        print(list(questions.keys())[i])
        ans = None
        while ans not in ['yes', 'no']:
            print("Please type yes or no.")
            ans = str(input()).lower()
        if ans == 'yes':
            if list(questions.values())[i][1] == "Yes":
                df = df[df.Section.isin(list(questions.values())[i][0]) ==
                        False]
        else:
            if list(questions.values())[i][1] == "No":
                df = df[df.Section.isin(list(questions.values())[i][0]) ==
                        False]
    return df
```

So you can transform it to this code:

```py
def questionnaire(df, questions=questions):
    for i in range(0, len(questions)):  #len(questions)-1):
        print(list(questions.keys())[i])
        ans = None
        while ans not in ['yes', 'no']:
            print("Please type yes or no.")
            ans = str(input()).lower()
        question = list(questions.values())[i]
        if question[1] == ans.title():
            df = df[df.Section.isin(question[0]) == False]
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue: Recursion, restarting the entire questionnaire again

You have so many lines in that loop over questions that you might not see the *recursion*:

```
def questionnaire(df, questions = questions):
    for i in range(0, len(questions)): #len(questions)-1):
        # your code omitted for clarity
        else:
            print("Please type yes or no.")
            questionnaire(df, questions = questions)  # RECURSION! Starting the questionnaire over again
```

Let's clean the scene with some refactoring first. Then we can try to fix the issue. Instead of recursion we need a loop.

#### Refactor: Extract functions to have the loop short and clean

First let us add some comments that explain the abstractions (what your code is intended to do):

```
def questionnaire(df, questions = questions):
    # ask all questions, one at a time
    for i in range(0, len(questions)):  # for each question
        print(list(questions.keys())[i])  # ask current question
        
        ans = str(input())  # get user input as answer
        if ans.lower() == 'yes':
            # verify if given answer (title-cased YES) was expected
            if list(questions.values())[i][1] == "Yes":
                df = df[df.Section.isin(list(questions.values())[i][0]) == False]
        elif ans.lower() == 'no':
            # verify if given answer (title-cased NO) was expected
            if list(questions.values())[i][1] == "No":
                df = df[df.Section.isin(list(questions.values())[i][0]) == False]
        else:
            # if given answer is invalid (not in set of expected answers), ask again 
            print("Please type yes or no.")
            questionnaire(df, questions = questions)
        
    return df
```

Using the comments we can see similarities and refactor this.
Also taking some improvements:

- assume `questions` is a Python dict of *key* `question` mapped to *value* `answer_options`.
  Instead of iterating with for-i and then indexing you can use for-each like `for question, answer_tuple in questions_dict.items()` then replace `list(questions.keys())[i]` to `question` and `list(questions.values())[i]` to `answer_tuple`.
- instead `print(question); ans = input()` you can directly prompt `input(question)`

```
def ask(question):
   # ask current question
   return str(input(question))  # get user input as answer


def store_answer(df, expected)
    return df[df.Section.isin(expected) == False]


def collect_answer(df, question, answer_tuple):
        ans = ask(question)
        while ans.lower() not in  {'yes', 'no'}:
            print("Invalid answer. Please type either yes or no.")
            ans = ask(question)

        # valid answer to store
        if ans.title() == answer_tuple[1]:  # if correct answer given
            return store_answer(df, answer_tuple[0])
        return df

def questionnaire(df, questions_dict = questions):
    # ask all questions, one at a time
    for question, answer_tuple in questions_dict.items():  # for each dict entry (question with answer_tuple)
        df = collect_answer(df, question, answer_tuple)
    return df
```

#### Fixed by Pattern: Loop until valid input

Instead of the recursion with `questionnaire(df, questions)` we just ask for the current question again in a loop until valid input was given:

```
    ans = ask(question)
    while ans.lower() not in {'yes', 'no'}:
        print("Invalid answer. Please type either yes or no.")
        ans = ask(question)
    # valid answer to store
```

If no valid answer was given, then it only asks the current question again ... as long as the answer is not in the set of valid options `{'yes', 'no'}`.
As soon as this `while` loop exits, we know the answer is valid and can continue.